# Using the History Web API from WKWebView & Cordova

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wkwebview, hybrid

I am creating a hybrid app using React / Create React App / Cordova. Due to several issues with the UIWebView such as floating cursors and general substandard rendering I've switched to using the WKWebView. The WKWebView has improved the rendering issues but I'm having an issue with the History Web API.

As part of my core nav/routing I'm pushing a value which represents the current page into the history API using the line below. I then pop the values when needed and pass to a custom router. This works fine using UIWebView but not with WKWebView due to a security issue.

`window.history.pushState({pageId: pageId}, null, action.pageId);`

When pushing I'm getting the following error (NOTE : I've replaced IDs with {HASH} for this post) :

`SecurityError: Blocked attempt to use history.pushState() to change session history URL from file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{HASH}/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/{HASH}/App.app/www/index.html to file:///Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{HASH}/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/{HASH}/App.app/www/login. Paths and fragments must match for a sandboxed document.`

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure whether its a long term solution as I'm yet to fully investigate, but this seems to prevent the error : https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix

Comment: are you still using this xhrfix plugin? I have the same issue you had and the plugin worked for me (thank you!). Worth noting that the older oracle plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

**My project**

React JS + Cordova

**Issue**

```
SecurityError: Blocked attempt to use history.pushState() to change session history URL
Paths and fragments must match for a sandboxed document.
```

**Solution**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

*Very simple solution but it took me days of research to piece it all together.*

## Big thanks to the plugin writers!